# Spray-json formats for class hierarchy with subclass that references base class

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a class hierarchy that represents filter types, and one of the types contains a list of the base types. I cannot figure out how to set up spray-json formats for these types because the formatters for the base type and the containing type need to refer to each other.

Let's start with a class hierarchy and json formats where the problematic parts are commented out:

```
object Filters {
  sealed trait Filter
  case class SimpleFilter(foo: String) extends Filter
  case class DoubleFilter(foo: String, bar: String) extends Filter
  implicit val simpleFormat = jsonFormat1(SimpleFilter)
  implicit val doubleFormat = jsonFormat2(DoubleFilter)

//  case class AndFilter(filters: List[Filter]) extends Filter
//  implicit val andFormat = lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(AndFilter))    

  // (would really use a type field, keeping simple for example)
  implicit val filterFormat = new RootJsonFormat[Filter] {
    override def write(obj: Filter): JsValue = obj match {
      case x: SimpleFilter => x.toJson
      case x: DoubleFilter => x.toJson
//    case x: AndFilter => x.toJson
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue): Filter = json.asJsObject.getFields("bar") match {
      case Seq(_) => json.convertTo[DoubleFilter]
      case Seq()  => json.convertTo[SimpleFilter]
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles and works as expected, I can serialize and deserialize concrete filter subclasses as Filter no problem.

But let's comment in the `AndFilter` stuff. Now there is trouble! With  the declaration of `andFormat` ahead of `filterFormat` (as above), it won't compile because `andFormat` needs `filterFormat`:

> Error:(17, 43) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol.JF[List[classpath.Filters.Filter]]
>         implicit val andFormat = jsonFormat1(AndFilter)

Switching the order around to `andFormat` after `filterFormat` will let things compile. But of course I also want to add `andFormat`-referencing clauses to `filter` format, i.e. `case x: AndFilter => x.toJson` in the write method and whatever including `json.convertTo[AndFilter]` in the read method. And that doesn't compile either:

> Error:(23, 34) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for classpath.Filters.Filter with classpath.Filters.AndFilter
>             case x: AndFilter => x.toJson

I can't find any way around this. I've tried spray-json's `lazyFormat` but it doesn't help (only works for recursive self references, not a cross reference like this). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following modification resolves the issue with *implicit resolution* of `JsonFormat[AndFilter]`, stated in the question.

```scala
implicit val andFormat: JsonFormat[AndFilter] = lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(AndFilter))
```

Please note that, we need to supply explicit type annotation (i.e.,`JsonFormat[AddFilter]`) for `andFormat` so that `SparyJsonSupport` can pick it up as an instance of  `RootJsonFormat`, instead of `JsonFormat` returned by `lazyFormat`:

```scala
  import spray.json._
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._

  object Filters {
    sealed trait Filter
    case class SimpleFilter(foo: String) extends Filter
    case class DoubleFilter(foo: String, bar: String) extends Filter
    case class AndFilter(filters: List[Filter]) extends Filter

    implicit val simpleFormat = jsonFormat1(SimpleFilter)
    implicit val doubleFormat = jsonFormat2(DoubleFilter)
    implicit val andFormat: JsonFormat[AndFilter] = lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(AndFilter))

    implicit val filterFormat = new RootJsonFormat[Filter] {
      override def write(obj: Filter): JsValue = ???
      override def read(json: JsValue): Filter = ???
    }
  }
```

For details: please see https://github.com/spray/spray-json#jsonformats-for-recursive-types.

Comment: Excellent! I had tried using `lazyFormat` when I was originally playing with this, but maybe without the explicit type annotation? Or perhaps some other user error - in any case I couldn't get it to work. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to help the compiler a bit. Adding an explicit type on the `filterFormat` and an explicit `write` will make it compile.

```
sealed trait Filter
case class SimpleFilter(foo: String) extends Filter
case class DoubleFilter(foo: String, bar: String) extends Filter
case class AndFilter(filters: List[Filter])
implicit val simpleFormat = jsonFormat1(SimpleFilter)
implicit val doubleFormat = jsonFormat2(DoubleFilter)
implicit val andFormat    = jsonFormat1(AndFilter)

implicit val filterFormat: RootJsonFormat[Filter] = new RootJsonFormat[Filter] {
  override def write(obj: Filter): JsValue = obj match {
    case x: SimpleFilter => x.toJson
    case x: DoubleFilter => x.toJson
    case x: AndFilter    => andFormat.write(x)
  }

  override def read(json: JsValue): Filter = json.asJsObject.getFields("bar") match {
    case Seq(_) => json.convertTo[DoubleFilter]
    case Seq()  => json.convertTo[SimpleFilter]
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh. Duh! (In my defense I've been setting up a protocol and set up dozens of case classes in several hierarchies and had sort of forgotten that things don't **have** to be implicit. :) )

Comment: Unfortunately though, while that compiles, it does not work. Trying to serialize an `AndFilter` throws a null pointer exception down in `spray.json.CollectionFormats`, calling `spray.json.PimpedAny.toJson`, where it appears that the implicit `JsonWriter`, which should be the filter format, is null.  _Side note_ - my original code, which Pim copied, neglected to have `AndFilter` extend `Filter`. I'll edit.